# Parse php generated png in html

Tags: php, png, gd

I got a class that generates a png showing the result on a single page

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
header('Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0'); // HTTP/1.1
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT');

imagepng($png,'test.png');
imagedestroy($png);
```

Instead of above, that prints the png successfully, I need to use the script so it generates several dynamically created pngs and be able to parse them in an html page.

Therefore I tried to uncomment the headers and return $png:

```
return $png;
```

and on the other side parse it

```
$png = $obj->pngGeneratorFuntion(1,30,'blank');
imagepng($png);
imagedestroy($png);
```

The results looks like this

```
�PNG  IHDR.i ��PLTE���U��~tRNS@��fIDAT�c�$=�*y ���K�S����)IEND�B`��PNG  IHDR.i ��PLTE���U��~tRNS@��fIDAT�c�$i]���a�P�{O��;>IEND�B`��PNG  IHDR.i ��PLTE���U��~tRNS@��fIDAT�c�$Y����a�P�OMY�)"IEND�B`��PNG  IHDR.i ��PLTE���U��~tRNS@��fIDAT�c�$yZ/y ���TKX{U#8MIEND�B`��PNG  IHDR.i ��PLTE���U��~tRNS@��fIDAT�c�$<�2y ���>�Sq��M�IEND�B`�
```

and print_r($png) gives

```
Resource id #7
```

How can I achieve this. Thanks!

Comment: A PNG is an IMAGE file, binary .. how can you parse it in HTML? What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: why not store all the png file into the folder?? something like `imagepng('folder/'.$png);`

Comment: Are you sure the result just looks like that because you haven't issued: `header('Content-Type: image/png');` before outputting the image (`image_png($png)`)?

Answer (score 3):

You can try [base64_encode()](http://uk.php.net/base64_encode) this if you want to insert the image directly in `HTML` tags:

```
$png = $obj->pngGeneratorFuntion(1,30,'blank');
echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($png).'">';
```

But it's not a good solution to insert image data directly into `HTML`

You can make a separate file `image_process.php` and send the data to that file with `$_GET` parameters and return image content. Then you can use:

```
<img src="image_process.php?text=ImageText" alt="" />
```

Comment: I got this to work: imagepng($png,'foo.png'); imagedestroy($png); $code = '<img src="foo.png" />';

Is it still better to make a separate file? Why is that required?

Comment: It is required for all browsers to display correct the image. And for clean HTML.